# Migrating Application from Tomcat V 8.5 to Websphere Application Server

Tags: websphere

When I am trying to deploy my war file from tomcat to websphere I am getting the following error.
1)org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
2)org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
3)java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory

I tried by changing the class loader from parent first to parent last(Vice-Versa).But still I am getting same error

Help me out.

Comment: To which version are you migrating? If you are migrating from Tomcat I'd strongly recommend to migrate to the latest WebSphere Liberty version (19.0.0.1 at the time of writing). Liberty more recommended that traditional WAS, when migrating from Tomcat.

Comment: @Gas Websphere Application Traditional Server 8.5

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially several issues with your app:

1. You probably include Java EE jars in your application - like jee.jar, servlet.jar etc - please remove all these jars from `WEB-INF/lib` directory.
2. It looks like you are bundling your own web services engine (CXF) inside your application. tWAS provides its own web services engine. So you either need to migrate to the provided or disable tWAS one. Check the [Using a third-party JAX-WS web services engine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html) page. You will need to  set `DisableIBMJAXWSEngine` property and configure module classloader for your `war` to `parent last`.

I still would recommend migrating to Liberty if possible, instead of traditional.